# SQL Query Optimization (Mysql 5.7)

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I have following query to execute in live mysql 5.7, which takes around 7 sec and we want to reduce their time, please support

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(
          DISTINCT InternalInquiry.inquiry_id
     ) AS "count" 
FROM
     internal_inquiries `InternalInquiry` 
     LEFT JOIN cpml_projects `Project` 
          ON (
               Project.project_id = InternalInquiry.object_id 
               AND Project.agent_id = 159297
          ) 
     INNER JOIN clients `Client` 
          ON (
               Client.clientid = InternalInquiry.clientID
          ) 
     INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT DISTINCT 
               (InternalInquiry.inquiry_id) AS "id" 
          FROM
               internal_inquiries `InternalInquiry` 
                LEFT JOIN internal_inquiries_sharing `InternalInquirySharing` 
                    ON (
                         InternalInquiry.inquiry_id = InternalInquirySharing.inquiry_id 
                    )
          WHERE (
                    (
                      InternalInquiry.userid IN ( 399724, 420710, 438389, 535916, 535917, 541643, 541644)
                       OR InternalInquirySharing.share_with IN ( 399724, 420710, 438389, 535916, 535917, 541643, 541644)
                     ) 
               ) 
               AND  (
                    InternalInquiry.status IN (
                         1, 21, 26, 14, 4, 15, 13, 5, 16, 17, 18, 22, 25, 2, 10, 3, 19, 20, 23, 11, 12, 24, 9, 8, 28
                    )
               ) 
               AND (
                    InternalInquiry.time_added >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
                    AND InternalInquiry.time_added <= '2018-11-22 23:59:59'
               )) dd 
          ON dd.id = InternalInquiry.inquiry_id 
WHERE (
          InternalInquiry.firmstate != 'deleted'
     ) 
     AND (
          InternalInquiry.status IN (
               1, 21, 26, 14, 4, 15, 13, 5, 16, 17, 18, 22, 25, 2, 10, 3, 19, 20, 23, 11, 12, 24, 9, 8, 28
          )
     ) 
     AND (
          InternalInquiry.time_added >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' 
          AND InternalInquiry.time_added <= '2018-11-22 23:59:59'
     ) 
     AND (
           Client.client_status != 1 AND
           Client.client_agency = 159297
     )
```

Execution plan as follow:

```
    id  select_type  table                   partitions  type    possible_keys                                                                                                         key                               key_len  ref                                       rows  filtered  Extra                         
------  -----------  ----------------------  ----------  ------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------------------------  -------  --------------------------------------  ------  --------  ------------------------------
     1  PRIMARY      <derived2>              (NULL)      ALL     (NULL)                                                                                                                (NULL)                            (NULL)   (NULL)                                  143661    100.00  (NULL)                        
     1  PRIMARY      InternalInquiry         (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,clientID,time_added,firmstate,search_inquiry_basic_index                                                      PRIMARY                           4        dd.id                                        1     12.50  Using where                   
     1  PRIMARY      Client                  (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,client_agency,client_status,com_1                                                                             PRIMARY                           4        InternalInquiry.clientID                     1     25.00  Using where                   
     1  PRIMARY      Project                 (NULL)      ref     project_id                                                                                                            project_id                        5        InternalInquiry.object_id                    1    100.00  Using where                   
     2  DERIVED      InternalInquiry         (NULL)      ALL     PRIMARY,clientID,userid,object_type,next_status_wanted,time_added,firmstate,search_inquiry_basic_index,idx_object_id  (NULL)                            (NULL)   (NULL)                                  544996     25.00  Using where; Using temporary  
     2  DERIVED      InternalInquirySharing  (NULL)      ref     internal_inquiries_sharing_UN,inquiry_id                                                                               internal_inquiries_sharing_UN    5        InternalInquiry.inquiry_id                   1    100.00  Using where; Using index
```

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481249/sql-query-optimization-mysql-5-7

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LEFT` unless you are going to use the 'optional' nature it provides.  The `EXPLAIN` seems to imply that the first `LEFT` made no sense in your case.  (I can't tell about the other `LEFT`.)

These indexes *might* help:

```
InternalInquiry:  INDEX(status, time_added)   -- in this order
Project:          INDEX(project_id, agend_id) -- in either order
```

`OR` inhibits optimizations; consider trying to avoid it.

To further analyze the query, please figure out how long the derived table (subquery) is taking.  It looks like it can be run independently.